# List all sub categories names on custom homepage using static block

Tags: category, home

I want to show all sub categories names like a menu on my `custom homepage` pleas e see the image below.

On the right hand side is slider which is coming from `custom static block` and below the slider there are 3 banners they are also coming from `custom static block` on the left hands side there is a menu which i want to come from categories currently it is only `HTML`

[image]

**EDIT**

I want left menu to come from magento sub-categories. `from default categories` created in admin panel. I want to display those created categories here in below image left hand side.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you expected? What doesn't work? Please help us to help you. We help solving problems, not solving problems.

Comment: I've made an edit in my question.!
please comment if you still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to achieve, but not what your problem is, so I give you an overview how to achieve this:

Use `\Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`, create your own block and template, use `\Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::getCurrentChildCategories` to get the child categories and show them